# How do I change the color of my Dock on Mac

Tags: macos, finder, dock

I am digging deep into my Mac's files to try and find how to change the color of my mac's dock. I have been able to change little things like the separator, indicator light, trash can, finder icon, etc. But I cannot find the file where the color of the actual Dock is.

I used this code to immediately go to the Dock folder

/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources

If you want a picture please ask and I'll edit a good one so you get the idea.

Comment: Check this http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1495519

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no image that you can change to change the background of the Dock. However, you can give the image to [**DockMod**](http://www.dockmod.com) which will let you change the background.

[image]

Comment: Beware clicking the DockMod link; it appears the app is no longer maintained and the link prompts for Flash Player upgrade (likely indicator of malware). The company's website (Spryesoft) appears to no longer exist.